# Bluemix.net's Wordpress boilerplate not sending emails

Tags: wordpress, email, sendgrid, ibm-cloud

So I created a Wordpress page using a Bluemix boilerplate. Everything is working fine except for the email notifications. When a new user registers they don't get an email with their temp password. If I click on "forgot password" and provide an email I get the following error: "The e-mail could not be sent.
Possible reason: your host may have disabled the mail() function."

Anyone know what needs to be configured? I see that the Wordpress boilerplate comes with a Sendgrid service, but when I click on "Open Sendgrid Dashboard" I get a blank page.

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: install a SMTP plugin and test it once. if it fails, then contact hosting server administrator

Comment: I was able to go to https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/mail.html and send a test email, so my auto-generated sendgrid account works. Something is just missing on the bluemix side.

Comment: Hmmm just noticed something strange... in my dashboard the Sendgrid service shows "Unbound Service" however when I try to bind it, it says "Bound to: MyApp". Wonder if that has anything to do with this behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok never mind... figured it out. Posting answer in case someone else runs into the same thing.

Turns out you have to go to the Wordpress Admin Dashboard -> Plugins -> Installed Plugins and "Activate" the SendGrid Plugin. Once you do that you then have to click on settings and configure by using your SendGrid account info (Which can be found on your Bluemix dashboard).

Comment: Glad you figured this out. Can you please mark your answer as "accepted"? Also, if you had to do anything else to get SendGrid set up, it would be helpful to outline those steps as well as an edit to your answer.

Comment: Can't accept my answer until tomorrow I'm being told by the nice red pop-up. I didn't have to do anything other than copy and paste the user id / password into the settings. However according to Bluemix development they have updated the boilderplate to auto start & configure sendgrid so no one else should run into this issue: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/181934/bluemixnets-wordpress-boilerplate-not-sending-emai/?smartspace=bluemix